# C++ Windows.h Crear ventana en proyecto Vacío en Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, winapi

He intentado crear un proyecto vacío y luego crear una ventana haciendo uso de la librería `Windows.h` (WINAPI) con la instrucción `CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, ...` a lo cual tengo como resultado una ventana con titulo que muestra un solo carácter, es decir si mi ventana tiene por titulo "Mi ventana" solo se muestra "M".
Luego intente creando un proyecto del tipo "Aplicación de escritorio de Windows" peor me tope con el problema del encabezado `stdafx.h` el cual no pude quitar facilmente

Answer (score 0):

Mi solución fue.
Crear un proyecto "Aplicacion de escritorio de Windows" luego en
propiedades de proyecto
  C/C++
    Encabezados de precompilacion
      Encabezado precompilado: No usar
Y las dos opciones restantes dejarlas vacías.

Luego en el archivo `TuProyeto.vcxproj` buscar las líneas que tengan `<PrecompiledHeader>Use</PrecompiledHeader>` y cambiar a `<PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>` Lo que estamos haciendo es decirle al compilador que no use los ecabezados precompilados

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <ClCompile>
      <PrecompiledHeader>NotUsing</PrecompiledHeader>
```

Por cierto, el no usar encabezados precompilados en proyectos grandes donde si que se tendrán mas librerías que ya no se tocaran, hará que cada compilación recompile todo de nuevo haciendo que demore el proceso de compilación por algo que ya se tiene compilado.

En un proyecto vacío de c++ no se porque solo me funciona con la compilacion de 64 bits pero en el archivo `TuProyeto.vcxproj` buscando la etiqueta `link` su contenido se reemplaza por el siguiente

```
      <SubSystem>Windows</SubSystem>
      <EnableCOMDATFolding>true</EnableCOMDATFolding>
      <OptimizeReferences>true</OptimizeReferences>
      <GenerateDebugInformation>true</GenerateDebugInformation>
```

y podrán compilar sin tener ese error del titulo con un solo carácter.
El origen verdadero del problema aun no lo encuentro, si alguien lo sabe gracias por su ayuda